# Record Not reflected in data-base until loop not completed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update multiple records in Database one - by - one (Using Loop), **code work fine**, but the problem is records not reflected in data-base until loop not completed, (if i abort the loop manual then its not working )

I want to reflect changes instant on each iteration

following are the code:

```
        @Transactional(value = "emailMgmtDSTransactionManager")
        @Repository
        public class PRODFlgUpdateDaoImp implements PRODFlgUpdateDao {

                @PersistenceContext(unitName = "emailMgmtDSEmFactory")
                @Qualifier
                EntityManager entityManager;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public int UpdateProdFlg() {
            List<FactEmailReport> report = entityManager
                            .createQuery("from FactEmailReport d where d.hardBounced='1' and d.fProdUpdate is null")
                            .getResultList();


                     //LOOP - Iterator 
                    for (FactEmailReport emailList : report) {

                            List<DimCompany> cmp = entityManager.createQuery("from DimCompany c where c.email=:email")
                                    .setParameter("email", emailList.getSentTo()).getResultList();
                            if (cmp.size() != 0) {
                                cmp.get(0).setIsEmailValide("1");
                                entityManager.merge(cmp.get(0));
                            }
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the ``@Transactional`` annotation. Let us know if it works.

Comment: not , its not working

Comment: Do you have the ``@Transactional`` annotation in any of the calling classes? That is: your "Service" or "Controller" classes? The annotation must be removed in all those places otherwise everything will be wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: No , annotation in any of the calling classes

Comment: You can put the code of updating the record in another method and annotating it with @Transactional instead of annotating the whole Class.
Also, you can try TransactionTempalate.